# An Iterator which mutates and returns the same object. Bad practice?

Tags: java, iterator, guava

I'm writing GC friendly code to read and return to the user a series of `byte[]` messages. Internally I reuse the same [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) which means I'll repeatedly return the same `byte[]` instance *most of the time*.

I'm considering writing cautionary javadoc and exposing this to the user as a [`Iterator<byte[]>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). AFAIK it won't violate the `Iterator` contract, but the user certainly could be surprised if they do [`Lists.newArrayList(myIterator)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28java.util.Iterator%29) and get back a `List` populated with the same `byte[]` in each position!

The question: is it **bad practice** for a class that **may mutate and return the same object** to implement the `Iterator` interface?

- If so, what is the best alternative? "Don't mutate/reuse your objects" is an easy answer. But it doesn't address the cases when reuse is very desirable.
- If not, how do you justify violating the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)?

Two minor notes:

- I'm using Guava's [`AbstractIterator`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.html) so remove() isn't really of concern.
- In my use case the user is *me* and the visibility of this class will be limited, but I've tried to ask this generally enough to apply more broadly.

**Update:** I'm accepting Louis' answer because it has 3x more votes than Keith's, but note that in my use case I'm planning to take the code that I left in a comment on Keith's answer to production.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`EnumMap` did essentially exactly this in its `entrySet()` iterator, which causes confusing, crazy, depressing bugs to this day.

If I were you, I just wouldn't use an `Iterator` -- I'd write a different API (possibly quite dissimilar from Iterator, even) and implement that.  For example, you might write a new API that takes as *input* the `ByteBuffer` to write the message into, so users of the API could control whether or not the buffer gets reused.  That seems reasonably intuitive (the user can write code that obviously and cleanly reuses the `ByteBuffer`), without creating unnecessarily cluttered code.

Comment: Great pointer. I started down the road of a non-Iterator impl but it was just turning into... a sad iterator in disguise :)  
  
So I tried out Keith's suggestion. If you like, take a look at the impl/test I left in his answer's comments and see if it still feels dangerous.

Comment: Wow - I'd completely forgotten about EnumMap.  Thanks, now side-effecting nightmares are going to keep me up at night for the rest of the week!  ;-)

Comment: Good news on the "bugs to this day" front: this behavior was fixed in Java 7.

Answer (score 7):

I would define an intermediate object which you can invalidate.  So your function would return an `Iterator<ByteArray>`, and `ByteArray` is something like this:

```
class ByteArray {
    private byte[] data;
    ByteArray(byte[] d) { data = d; }
    byte[] getData() {
        if (data == null) throw new BadUseOfIteratorException();
        return data;
    }
    void invalidate() { data = null; }
}
```

Then your iterator can invalidate the previously returned `ByteArray` so that any future access (via `getData`, or any other accessor you provide) will fail.  Then at least if someone does something like `Lists.newArrayList(myIterator)`, they will at least get an error (when the first invalid `ByteArray` is accessed) instead of silently returning the wrong data.

Of course, this won't catch all possible bad uses, but probably the common ones.  If you're happy with never returning the raw `byte[]` and providing accessors like `byte get(int idx)` instead, then it should catch all cases.

You will have to allocate a new `ByteArray` for each iterator return, but hopefully that's a lot less expensive than copying your `byte[]` for each iterator return.

Comment: Killer idea! Hadn't seen that before. Happy to hear your critique of my manifestation: [test](http://code.google.com/p/brianfromoregon/source/browse/trunk/lang/src/test/java/com/brianfromoregon/lang/ExpiringIteratorTest.java) and [impl](http://code.google.com/p/brianfromoregon/source/browse/trunk/lang/src/main/java/com/brianfromoregon/lang/ExpiringIterator.java)

Answer (score 1):

Just like Keith Randall I'd also create `Iterator<ByteArray>`, but working quite differently (the annotations below come from [lombok](http://projectlombok.org)):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ByteArray {
    @Getter private final byte[] data;
    private final ByteArrayIterable source;
    void allowReuse() {
        source.allowReuse();
    }
}

public class ByteArrayIterable implements Iterable<ByteArray> {
    private boolean allowReuse;
    public allowReuse() {
        allowReuse = true;
    }
    public Iterator<ByteArray> iterator() {
        return new AbstractIterator<ByteArray>() {
            private ByteArray nextElement;
            public ByteArray computeNext() {
                if (noMoreElements()) return endOfData();
                if (!allowReuse) nextElement =
                    new ByteArray(new byte[length], ByteArrayIterable.this);
                allowReuse = false;
                fillWithNewData(lastElement.getData());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in calls like `Lists.newArrayList(myIterator)` always a new byte array gets allocated, so everything works. In your loops like

```
for (ByteArray a : myByteArrayIterable) {
    a.allowReuse();
    process(a.getData());
}
```

the buffer gets reused. No harm may result, unless you call `allowReuse()` by mistake. If you forget to call it, then you get worse performance but correct behavior.

---

Now I see it could work without `ByteArray`, the important thing is that `myByteArrayIterable.allowReuse()` gets called, which could be done directly.

Comment: I like your take on it, let the user decide when to reuse. I wrote an impl of Keith's idea and it has this twist of yours too, except the user specifies reuse when *creating* the iterator rather than when *using* it. Specifically check out the 'objectPool' test in the linked test file to see how the user could specify the size of the reuse pool. Cheers.

Comment: @Brian Harris: I wanted to be conservative... you must say "take this data, I don't care anymore" again and again, otherwise it won't be recycled. I did once something like this and like it this way, but I don't think it's necessary.