# Reusing a single object instead of creating new ones

Tags: java, arrays, object, optimization, memory-management

**Case study**
I've got a method that scan the file system for certain entries, and when found, stores them as new Objects.
These Objects include a couple of strings for the entry position and flags that represent the entry state.

As each new Object I instanciate occupies > 16 bytes, if 1000 entries are found I'm using (16 * 1000) bytes! As I need only one instance at a time, I'd like to reuse a single object (that is, using `new` a single time) and update its fields.

That's how I deal with the Objects now:

```
for (final Object object : scanFor(PATTERN)) {
  if (aName.equals(object.getName()) {
    ... use the object
  }
}
```

I thought I may use the same technique as ResultSet.
Any suggestion?

P.S. *I know 16kb of memory is nothing, but that's an example.*

EDIT: I see someone voted to close my question because it's unclear. I really don't know what else to write to be honest.

EDIT, real code:
*Caller*:

```
DspPgmRef dspPgmRef = new DspPgmRef("MYLIBRARY", "*ALL", J400Type.ALL);
dspPgmRef.addFilter(DspPgmRefEntryField.REFERENCED_OBJECT, name);

for (final DspPgmRefEntry entry : dspPgmRef.run()) {
   if (entry.referencedObject.equals(name)) {
      users.add(J400ObjectFactory.get("*LIBL", entry.object));
   }
}
```

*DspPgmRef* implementation:

```
public final class DspPgmRef implements J400Command<List<DspPgmRefEntry>>
{
   /**
    * Rappresenta un valore di ritorno del comando
    */
   public static class DspPgmRefEntry
   {
      public final String library;
      public final String object;
      public final String referencedLibrary;
      public final String referencedObject;
      public final String referencedType;

      public DspPgmRefEntry(
            final String library,
            final String object,
            final String referencedLibrary,
            final String referencedObject,
            final String referencedType) {
         this.library = library;
         this.object = object;
         this.referencedLibrary = referencedLibrary;
         this.referencedObject = referencedObject;
         this.referencedType = referencedType;
      }
   }

   /**
    * Campi dei riferimenti ritornati dal comando
    */
   public enum DspPgmRefEntryField
   {
      LIBRARY("WHLIB"),
      OBJECT("WHPNAM"),
      REFERENCED_LIBRARY("WHLNAM"),
      REFERENCED_OBJECT("WHFNAM"),
      REFERENCED_TYPE("WHOTYP");

      /**
       * Nome reale del campo di database
       */
      public final String value;

      private DspPgmRefEntryField(final String value) {
         this.value = value;
      }
   }

   private final String _library;
   private final String _object;
   private final J400Type _type;
   private final Map<DspPgmRefEntryField, String> _filters;

   {
      _filters = new EnumMap<>(DspPgmRefEntryField.class);
   }

   public DspPgmRef(final String library, final String object, final J400Type type) {
      _library = library;
      _object = object;
      _type = type;
   }

   public DspPgmRef(final J400GenericObject object) {
      this(object.getLibrary(), object.getName(), object.getType());
   }

   @Override
   public List<DspPgmRefEntry> run() {
      final String tempLibrary = J400Util.getRandomAS400String();
      final String tempFile = J400Util.getRandomAS400String();
      final int filtersSize = _filters.size();

      final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(120 + filtersSize * 20);
      builder.append("DSPPGMREF PGM(");
      builder.append(_library);
      builder.append("/");
      builder.append(_object);
      builder.append(") OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OBJTYPE(");
      builder.append(_type.ASType);
      builder.append(") OUTFILE(");
      builder.append(tempLibrary);
      builder.append("/");
      builder.append(tempFile);
      builder.append(")");

      final J400Connection connection = J400Connection.instance();
      connection.createLibrary(tempLibrary, "Libreria temporanea per DSPDBR");

      if (!connection.executeCommand(builder.toString()).containsKey("CPF3030")) {
         return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
      }

      builder.delete(0, builder.length());
      builder.append("select distinct WHPNAM, WHLNAM, WHFNAM, WHOTYP from ");
      builder.append(tempLibrary);
      builder.append(".");
      builder.append(tempFile);

      if (filtersSize > 0) {
         builder.append(" where ");

         for (final Entry<DspPgmRefEntryField, String> filter : _filters.entrySet()) {
            builder.append(filter.getKey().value);
            builder.append(" = '");
            builder.append(filter.getValue());
            builder.append("' and ");
         }

         final int stringLenght = builder.length();
         builder.delete(stringLenght - 5, stringLenght);
      }

      PreparedStatement statement = null;
      ResultSet result = null;

      try {
         statement = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(builder.toString());
         result = statement.executeQuery();

         final List<DspPgmRefEntry> references = new ArrayList<>(128);

         while (result.next()) {
            references.add(new DspPgmRefEntry(
                  _library,
                  result.getString(DspPgmRefEntryField.OBJECT.value).trim(),
                  result.getString(DspPgmRefEntryField.REFERENCED_LIBRARY.value).trim(),
                  result.getString(DspPgmRefEntryField.REFERENCED_OBJECT.value).trim(),
                  result.getString(DspPgmRefEntryField.REFERENCED_TYPE.value).trim()));
         }

         return Collections.unmodifiableList(references);
      } catch (final SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         try {
            if (result != null) {
               result.close();
            }

            if (statement != null) {
               statement.close();
            }
         } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

         connection.deleteLibrary(tempLibrary);
      }

      return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
   }

   public void addFilter(final DspPgmRefEntryField field, final String value) {
      _filters.put(field, value);
   }

   public void removeFilter(final DspPgmRefEntryField field) {
      _filters.remove(field);
   }

   public void clearFilters() {
      _filters.clear();
   }
}
```

Comment: How about using a lambda function in scanFor?

Comment: @brummfondel mmmh I can't figure out what you mean, can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Please post scanFor for better help.

Comment: It's unclear what you want, since you say you merely want to update its fields, and that's quite simple: you write setter methods. Is that what you want to know how to do?

Comment: You're talking about an immutable object, yet you wish to update its fields. That's what we call a paradox. Immutable objects are great if you can use them, but in this case you're barking up the wrong tree. Unless you *really* have an identified memory issue here, I'd say it's not worth it.

Comment: Title is wrong in itself. You cannot reuse immutable object instead of creating new objects. If you want to have different field for an immutable object, you have to create a new one. However, you can reuse mutable object by creating one and resetting its fields.

Comment: I added the real code to the question, so you guys can understand it.

Comment: This question is not clear to me. I think you might be after the [Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), which uses immutable *elementary* objects as values of the fields of more complex objects.

Comment: @Bohemian I know it's not easy to understand. Problably It's me also. Coming from C++ I'm too much into reducing memory footprint.

Comment: I removed the word _Immutable_ from the question title since it was clearly wrong based on your question. Basically, as I understand it, you are asking about the effects of re-using the same object over and over during iteration (updating its fields at each step), versus creating a new object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that what you are suggesting is performance impact and code smelliness of returning the *same object instance* from the `scanFor` method in this snippet:

```
for (final Object object : scanFor(PATTERN)) {
  if (aName.equals(object.getName()) {
    ... use the object
  }
}
```

Depending on the details of the rest of the code (e.g., how often the `equals` check is true and what happens in `... use the object`), this may indeed be a very large savings in allocation rate. It does, however, violate the commonly understood behavior of `Iterable<T>.iterator().next()` - which is that it *returns a unique object each time*. This has been discussed at [some length before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893479/an-iterator-which-mutates-and-returns-the-same-object-bad-practice). If you measure a performance increase that is significant to you using this trick, it may still be worth, but as always measure.

[Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) is included in the (Oracle) JDK and free for non-commercial use and can measure *actual* object allocation rates and locations. You can use this to verify if the temporary objects are a significant portion of your overall allocation (in some cases, inlining + escape analysis may be able to eliminate them completely, rendering your supposed issue moot).

Comment: Basically you're suggesting to create a custom iterator that always return the same object, just with changed properties.

Comment: And yeah, I absolutely need to learn how to use Mission Control! You're right!

Comment: @LppEdd - to be clear, that's what I thought _you_ were suggesting, and I was laying out some of the pros and cons. You said : "As I need only one instance at a time, I'd like to reuse a single object (that is, using new a single time) and update its fields." - and then you showed a loop that uses foreach (requiring Iterable). You can use your "one object, mutated" approach with Iterable, or you could just change your loop structure and avoid Iterable, which might be a bit clearer (since a future reader of the code could explicitly see one object being modified over and over).

Comment: If you look at the code posted above (the real one), you'll probably end up saying an iterator is the best choice, as I also need to fetch the result set. Thanks!